# UITextViewL link on xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a custom UITextView and need something like this:

```
<a href="www.google.es">Google</a>
```

By the way, This is my Initialize code on custom class:

```
void Initialize()
{
    Font = UIFont.FromName("Lacuna Regular", 14f);
    Editable = false;
    DataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorType.Link;
    Text = "Google";
}
```

but I don't know how to write the Url where I need to go (in this case, www.google.es).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via `UIDataDetectorType.Links`:

```
uiview.DataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorType.Link;
uiview.Text = @"https://www.google.es";
```

[image]

Via `NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributes` with `NSAttributedString`:

```
var urlString = @"<a href=""https://www.google.es"">Google</a>";
var documentAttributes = new NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributes { DocumentType = NSDocumentType.HTML };
NSError error = null;
var attributedString = new NSAttributedString(NSData.FromString(urlString, NSStringEncoding.UTF8), documentAttributes, ref error);
// Should really check the NSError before applying
uiview.AttributedText = attributedString;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second way was the best for me.

Comment: Another question! How could I add properties to the text like color, custom font...?

Comment: @user3535054 Just include the appropriate html in your `<span style="font-size:20px; color:#E44343;">StackOverflow</span>` For custom fonts, you have to include them in your app bundle and register them in your plist (search SO, there are a number of example for custom fonts, I believe I have answered one to two myself...)

Comment: Yeah, but when I have an anchor tag... I inserted styles in a span but doesn't work.

Comment: @user3535054 There are elements that Apple'e `HTML` to `NSAttributedString` that are not supported, it is not support !00% HTML5/CSS, there is a list of them somewhere on Apple's dev site... For complex attributed text, you would either need to handle it yourself, use a 3rd-party library, or use an UIWebView or MKWebView where appropriate